# vb.net for-each on a mongo database

Tags: vb.net, mongodb, foreach

I am using a for/each iteration to get the last document in a mongo database.  I pull this document every second and retrieve the 2nd element in the last document.  However, my database is probably going to get quite large and I worry this is not a very effective method.  Does anyone have any better ideas?  I'm new to mongo and vb.net and just trying to learn and track my car at the same time.

```
Dim counter As Integer

For Each item As BsonDocument In drivingData.FindAll()
Next
counter += 1
If counter = drivingData.FindAll().Count - 1 Then
Dim dataString As String = item.GetElement(1).Value.ToString()...
```

Comment: Do you have something you can sort on? You could invert the sort (-1), and then just limit the results to the "first" document (which would in fact be the last document).

Answer (score 0):

As was commented on, why not [sort](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) in reverse and [limit](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) your response document to 1.

Considering you are looking for the last document, even without another field such as a time to sort on the `_id` field will be returned in the order of insertion so you can reverse sort in this and the "last" document will then be the "first" result.

```
db.collection.find().sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm having trouble doing that as it says "Argument not specified for parameter query..."

Comment: That's a mongo shell method, right?  How would I do it in vb.net?  Sorry for my ignorance as I am really new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error I got the result.  Thanks for your repsonses as they eventually got through my thick skull:

```
Dim drivingValues As BsonArray
Dim lastDoc As BsonDocument

lastDoc = drivingData.FindAll().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("result")).Last
drivingValues = lastDoc.GetElement(1).Value
```